# Sharepoint 2013 - Remove [2] from webpart Title

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

My Home page with all the webparts has a number in brackets after the webpart title.

[image: Example Image]

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number gets added because you have multiple web parts configured with the same title. You need some change on the webpart's title to make the [2] disappear.

Alternatively, you might want to hide the webpart's title. Edit your webpart, expand the "Appearance" section, and select the option "None" on the "Chrome type" dropdown.

Comment: When I click on Site Contents to see all the apps I have for the page...the title is Team Announcements.  There is only one app on the Site Contents.  If I change the title on the home page to something else then the titles don't match when you look at site contents or the actual annoucements page.  If I keep the titles the same as the title in Site Contents then I get [3] after the title.

Comment: The solution from Oskarsforest is actually a better option as the actual problem is you have duplicate webparts.

Comment: @NickEagle He must've changed his name to "Oskar Z." in the interim, but yeah.

Answer (score 17):

Ok, I found a solution.

1. Stay at the page that you can see "**XXX [Number]**"
2. Click the "**Page**" button at the top-left corner
3. Click the "**Edit Properties**" button
4. Click the text(possibly blue) "**Open Web Part Page in maintenance view**"
5. Check the duplicate web parts you want to remove and click the "**delete**" button above.

(If you are NOT sure which are the web parts you want to keep, please delete them all and re-add the web parts you need. Otherwise, you might end up with some white space on the web part page.)

Comment: This is the answer!

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts, and didn't want to go out with a List View Web Part showing "[2]" beside the title after I had (I thought) deleted the first version I had created using the wrong view.  Next stop was going to be custom jQuery to hide it and wasn't looking forward to having to do something that SP should've been able to let you change by default.

Comment: Oskar, you have made my day. God bless you,

Answer (score 3):

This was driving me nuts too. Follow the steps here for the steps to delete it through the webpart maintenance page:

http://www.spdeveloper.co.in/tipsntricks/pages/opening-webpart-maintenance-page.aspx

Comment: Should always summarize steps from links rather than simply linking.  Links can become broken if they ever remove the content.

Answer (score 2):

Add a space after the title, this way you can use the same title for multiple webparts.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you should delete the "extra" duplicate web parts using the same title if they aren't visible on the page. But it's not unusual to want the *same* title showing for different web parts. In that scenario, a simple fix is to add a space after the title in the Appearance section of the duplicate web part's properties. If there are multiple web parts with the same title, just add more spaces. SP will treat the titles as unique.